# Magento 2 display block in product page only when product belongs to specific category

Tags: magento2, blocks, if

I have a block showing up near the add-to-cart button, but I would like to display it only in some products from specific categories.

Can i use something like this?

```
{{conditions_encoded="a:2:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]s:4:`1--1`;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Product`;s:9:`attribute`;s:12:`category_ids`;s:8:`operator`;s:2:`==`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`4`;]]"}}
```

Comment: If you add the block to a widget and specify for that to only appear on the specific products/categories?

Comment: tried that.  But you can only select single products or all products, no categories https://prnt.sc/fznmcq